# Too much chars in powerapps form? Can't submit a form

Tags: database, azure-sql-database, powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection

I have a problem after Submitting a form in PowerApps
All connectors are all right. Function also normally works, but I suppose maybe I have too much chars in my fields, so database can't save it.
I changed limits in DB for all records, but still something is wrong.
Some of fields are a HtmlText form, so I assumed that maybe there is a problem, but as you can see, I've managed to save it inside Azure DB

Thanks !

[DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpcpB.png)

[PowerApps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emgnI.png)

Comment: Hi @M33HoW, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. If you have any other concerns, please feel free to tell me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In previous, we can use [text or ntext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) data type.

But Text amd ntext data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

In Azure SQL database, column length has the length limit 255 .

Please try to modify your SQL table column schema to  nvarchar(max), varchar(max), or  varbinary(max) instead.

If the length of your data is exceeded the limit, there isn't a good solution for now.